# Unexpected EOF while parsing (parsing a dictionary)

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, syntax-error

Hello and good day to everyone!

I'm working on a data parser. It has to pull data from a webpage, store it in .txt file and then run a module to parse this .txt and create an .xls with data sorted as I want it to be.

I have three modules:
One is a "spider" that only extracts html from the pages.
The second one parses html and creates a dictionary with all required data.
The third one extracts the data from dict and creates an .xls from it.

Every module works fine on its own. I mean, if I execute it one by one manually, I wont get any error.
The problem is when I make this process to go automatically (calling the second module from the first one and the third from the second one) it crashes at the end calling:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/desprit/Documents/Python/examples/pg_parsing/data_parser.py", line 296, in <module>
    data_parser('verona')
  File "/home/desprit/Documents/Python/examples/pg_parsing/data_parser.py", line 285, in data_parser
    next_step(where)
  File "/home/desprit/Documents/Python/examples/pg_parsing/data_parser.py", line 292, in next_step
    save_to_excel_01.save_to_excel(where)
  File "/home/desprit/Documents/Python/examples/pg_parsing/save_to_excel_01.py", line 39, in save_to_excel
    imported_data = ast.literal_eval(imported_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I've checked everything and was googling for two days trying to figure out what to do but nothing.

**Here is the link to modules:**

**data_parser.py ---> http://codepad.org/nPH3LEay**

**save_to_excel.py ---> http://codepad.org/9kQ0IzKs**

**I also attach an example of the dict generated by data_parser.py ---> the_same_domain_as_above/XYPWMcgB**

As I see, unexpected EOF comes out when **ast.literal_eval()** starts to parse the dictionay.
But wtf? Dict is just ookay. In the same time when I execute save_to_excel.py manually at WORKS fine!

Sorry for so many stuff in modules. I've started to lear python couple of weeks ago and still doing tons of mistakes -.-

Ill be omfg happy if someone manages to help me! 
Thanks for your time!

P.S.
I'm adding here a part of code that (im not quite sure) causes a problem:

```
imported_file = open('pg_database/' + where + '/converted/' + file)
imported_data = imported_file.read()
imported_data = ast.literal_eval(imported_data)
```

Comment: Please do not provide link to codes. Post the __relevant__ code __in__ the question

Comment: Well, I dont mind to do that, but did you see that it has like 400 lines?
I didnt find any kind of drop-down lists to put the code inside of it... And im still not sure what part causes an error...

Comment: Then please post code that is relevant or that you think is causing the problem or the code that contains the error according to the Traceback

Comment: Ye, okay, I added it at the end of my topic. Again, these three lines work fine if I execute the module manually. Thats the most wierd part for me...

Comment: Do you convert / modify dict somewhere at the midddle? (I won't read the all code, I am not immortal)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
The dict is stored in txt file. I read the file to string and then I'm calling ast.literal_eval to convert this string to dict. 
After that I just read this dict line by line and without changing anything just send lines to xls file.
So no, I do not modify my dict...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a week and while working on another project I accidentally figured out what was the problem. Sir Cox asked me in comments above about editing the dict/tuple. But now I see that I didnt get his question.

```
data = open('name.txt')
data = data.read()
converted_data = ast.literal_eval(data)
```

This causes EOL error if you were editing your name.txt before in the same code and DIDNT close() it. Lets say you had a tuple and u were storing it in file:

```
saver = open('name.txt', 'w')
saver.write(str(our_tuple))
saver.close()   # you HAVE TO close it before opening it and calling ast.literal_eval on it's data. Otherwise you will get a EOL error.
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but closing the file didn't seem to help.  I open a file, read the results into a list, **close the file**, and then run `ast.literal_eval()` and still get the error.